# How to consume REST URLs using Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have developed few RESTful methods and exposed them via Apache Cxf

I'm developing the client side application using Spring MVC and I'm looking for a simple example to demonstrate how to call/consume these REST methods using Spring MVC

I know how to do it using Apache http client but prefer to use Spring MVC in case such this has already been implemented there.

Comment: Have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-rest-hello-world-example/) for a very simple example.

Comment: I'm having hard time trying to figure out what is being asked here: Do you want to use a Spring MVC-application between the browser and another RESTful -service as a sort-of proxy, or just reimplement some RESTful-service using Spring MVC?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Spring provides simple wrapper to consume RESTful services called [`RestTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html). It performs path variable resolution, marshalling and unmarshalling:

```
Map<String, Integer> vars = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
vars.put("hotelId", 42);
vars.put("roomId", 13);
Room room = restTemplate.getForObject(
  "http://example.com/hotels/{hotelId}/rooms/{roomId}", 
  Room.class, vars);
```

Assuming `Room` is a JAXB object which can be understood by The `RestTemplate`.

Note that this class has nothing to do with Spring MVC. You can use it in MVC application, but also in a standalone app. It is a client library.

## See also

- [REST in Spring 3: RestTemplate](http://blog.springsource.org/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate/)

Answer (score 1):

Use path variables to consume REST data. For example:

```
https://localhost/products/{12345}
```

This pattern should give you the detail of the product having product id 12345.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/products/{productId}")
@ResponseBody
public SomeModel doProductProcessing(@PathVariable("productId") String productId){
//do prpcessing with productid
return someModel;
}
```

If you want to consume Rest Service from another service then have a look at:

> http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html

and

> http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=546

Comment: I'm not sure that your example really helps, as the REST API already exists. I think the question is asking about how to map this with Spring MVC into classes that the rest of his client can consume.

Comment: If I understood correctly, the OP wants the Spring MVC app to be a *client* of another RESTful application.

Comment: I have added a simple method to grab the product id from URL pattern